# IronPython how to write a double constant

Tags: c#, ironpython

I need to write a double constant inside my python code, something like:

```
a = 15.523
```

The problem is, this constant is considered as a 'float' inside C#. I want that constant to be instantiated as a 'double'. I tryed the C# suffix notation where you would write:

```
a = 15.523d
```

But I get a syntax error.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: unexpected token 'd'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IronPython float is a C# double. There's an automatic conversion to float where necessary, but internally it's System.Double.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the CLR double type you can do this

```
>>> import clr
>>> from System import Double
>>> d = Double(15.523)
>>> d.GetType()    
<System.RuntimeType object at <...> [System.Double]>
```